# How can I deal with an error of a line about Swift code in WWDC 2014

Tags: swift

I followed WWDC 2014 session 403 to write the code in Playground file:

```
var onChange:(Int)->Void = {}
```

But I got an error: 'Int' is not a subtype of '{}' , why? That line is exactly the same as the one in the video.

The entire code is:

```
class TemperatureNotifier {
     var onChange:(Int)->Void = {} 
     var currentTemp = 72

     init() {
          onChange = { temp in
               self.currentTemp = temp
           }
     }
}
```

Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: @MechEthan That didn't work for me. Does your code compile?

Comment: @CezaryWojcik Sorry, it didn't work after cleaning up some surrounding code. -- I'm pretty sure I had other things hiding the problem.  (Deleted my original comment due to misinformation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with the current version of Swift that we have access to, I've found that if you have any arguments in the closure, that kind of error pops up. In order to fix it, you have to give the close the `in` syntax:

```
class TemperatureNotifier {
    var onChange : (Int) -> Void = {x in}
    var currentTemp = 72

    init() {
        self.onChange = { temp in
            self.currentTemp = temp
        }
    }
}
```

It seems silly - especially since you got this code from a session video - this is probably a bug in Swift. You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have filed a bug #17227104 to Apple.

Comment: Possibly related: I've noticed that `numbers.map { n in "test" }` works, but `numbers.map { "test" }` is an error. Although, oddly, `numbers.map { String($0) }` is not.

Comment: Page 161 of TSPL: *"If you use these shorthand argument names within your closure expression, you can omit the closure’s argument list from its definition, and the number and type of the shorthand argument names will be inferred from the expected function type."*